# Saving the database backup on server instead of pushing to user

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Below is how I am generating the MySql database backup and forcing it to be downloaded on the users computer:

```
    $DBUSER=$this->db->username;
    $DBPASSWD=$this->db->password;
    $DATABASE=$this->db->database;

    $filename = $DATABASE . "-" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".sql.gz";
    $mime = "application/x-gzip";

    header( "Content-Type: " . $mime );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );

    // $cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best";   
    $cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best";

    // Instead of the above command, I have tried the following command to save to the server but it didn't save
    // $save_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/assets/db_backups/' . $filename;
    // $cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best > " . $save_path;

    passthru( $cmd );
```

What I want is, instead of pushing to the user, **save it on the server**. How may I modify this to make the file be downloaded on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my code as follows, and it worked

```
$DBUSER=$this->db->username;
$DBPASSWD=$this->db->password;
$DATABASE=$this->db->database;

$filename = $DATABASE . "-" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".sql.gz";

$save_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/assets/db_backups/' . $filename;
$cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best > " . $save_path;

exec( $cmd );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Forcing a download using readfile()**

```
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Simple text to download:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
?>Hello, world.
```

Comment: if you didn't notice, the backup file already gets downloaded at the user's PC, what I want is to make the file be saved on the server.